# Visual Studio 2022 Git mistake How to undo all local changes

Tags: git, visual-studio

I screwed up! How do you undo all your changes, including project and file system deletes and adds to get my local repo back in sync with the remote repo using VS 2022?

How do I revert my local repo to the original state prior to all this? I never staged or committed anything. If that's not possible, what's the next best thing? I'd prefer to not have to push any changes, since I don't have any I want to keep, but I'm not sure that's possible.

Comment: Honestly the easiest thing is to just delete the whole local solution folder and check out everything again.

Comment: Micky, do you mean delete the solution folder and then run ```git clone``` or do you mean ```git checkout```. I thought git checkout was for switching to another branch?

Comment: Yes, delete the local repo folder containing the solution and everything else.  So if you Git cloned a remote Git project called **Sheep** into **c:\Dev\Sheep** and your **.sln** is in **c:\Dev\Sheep\src\Sheep.sln** then delete the folder **c:\Dev\Sheep** along with all child folders.   Earlier when I said _"check out"_ I meant _clone_.

Answer (score 2):

This will cover CLI instructions, since I'm not familiar with the Visual Studio interface. You can put the commands in your terminal. Ensure your current working directory is set to the root of your local repository.

---

If your goal is just to revert to exactly what's on the remote, then that should be fairly simple.

**Please ensure this is 100% what you want to do before you execute the commands. It can be difficult or impossible to recover the data.**

First, reset all tracked files in the repository. So, all modified/deleted files. This will reset everything except any new files you created.

```bash
git reset --hard origin/main
```

More Info: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset

If your remote name or branch name is different, use those values instead. You can use [`git remote`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote) and [`git branch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch) to check the names of remotes and branches on the repository.

Now delete all untracked files in the repository, so new files you created but have never committed yet:

```bash
git clean -f
```

More Info: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean

---

This isn't part of the question… but just in case.

If you find that you accidentally deleted a local commit that you need back, immediately stop what you're doing and look into [`git reflog`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog) to try and recover it!

If you accidentally delete files you never committed and realized you needed, Git can't help you here. You'd have to look into software for undeleting files, results may vary.

Comment: Thank you. Just before you answered I ran ```git clean -n``` to see what it would remove. It was only 39 files out of 48 total items. But I have no files that are staged. Every file in ```git status``` is untracked since I never did ```git add```.  I thought I should just run ```git clean -f``` . But the difference between git clean-n versus status shows different files, probably some folders. 

So now I'm thinking that it should indeed be ```git reset --hard origin/main```

Comment: Another thing I noticed is that Visual Studio says ```Changes (83)```  in the git section of solution explorer. That seems odd, to me.

Comment: It must be the deletes. I forget it tracks everything!